# Basemap rotation - keeping labels facing down

Tags: labeling, mapping, basemap, google, rotate

I'm using QGIS Hannover 3.16.3.
I often use Google basemap layers from the XYZ tiles. When rotating the maps the place names rotate with them. Is there a way of stopping this? Perhaps an alternative map source?

Comment: No, a basemap is a picture so there is nothing QGis can do to change it.

Comment: Not all "basemaps" are raster basemaps.

Comment: @bugmenot123 how do I find these non raster global basemaps? Are they free?

Comment: Look for vector tiles as suggested in the existing answer by @Vince already.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, you can't rotate a Google-XYZ-tiles map and keep the labes facing down. But there are alternatives.

An XYZ Tile map is a so-called **base-map**. You can think of it as if it were a **'photo of a map'** (albeit different photos at different zoom-levels). If you turn the map, it's like rotating a photo - the **labels will always remain facing the original direction**.

The same goes for WMS/WMTS.

However: Depending on where your AOI is located, you may be able to find a **Vector-Tile basemap**. One such example is the [Vector-Basemap](https://basemap.de/en/web-vektor/) by the BKG ministry of Germany. Here the layer-style, labels etc. are drawn dynamically, just like from a shapefile, where you can change things in the settings of the file. You can include it just like the XYZ-Tile and you need the associated layer-styling .json file.

Since the labels are drawn based on the attributes, just like from a normal shapefile, **you can also flip it with the labels always facing down**:

If you need a satllite-basemap with labels in the right orientation. I would use a sat-basemap without labels and ad places/roads etc. via shapefiles as a layer over it (can also be done with the vecotr-tile basemap.

[image]